# Running docker-machine as a snap vs standard installation

Tags: docker

My question is is there any notable difference between running Docker-Machine as a snap vs built from a source ? I'm having networking issue and I suspect it may be related to the type of installation.

this is what I get when I try point active host to the Docker:

executing:    `docker-machine env instance`

output:

```
Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates for host
```

after executing: `docker-machine -D regenerate-certs instance`

output:

```
SSH cmd err, output: fork/exec /usr/bin/ssh: permission denied: 
Error getting ssh command 'exit 0' : ssh command error:
command : exit 0
err     : fork/exec /usr/bin/ssh: permission denied
```

Changing permissions for the mentioned directory didn't help.

Comment: just a curiosity because I don't think I can help here: I assume you're using an ubuntu distribution since you're using snap, so why do you use the `docker-machine` instead of using docker natively?

Comment: Well ... I installed docker-machine using the Ubuntu package manager and it downloaded and installed it as a snap. Otherwise I'd have to go out and compile it from source.

Comment: I ask because you don't really need a docker-machine since docker is supposed to be running natively on your machine. Moreover on Ubuntu you can use the official packages: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

Comment: I uninstalled the snap and installed the official build from the link you provided. Same result. Looks like this SSH problem isn't just me as I've read a lot about this on GitHub with no clear solution to it though. Looks like this isn't installation-type dependent error.

Comment: I still don't understand why you need the docker-machine. I've never had to install it on a linux machine. So I wonder if it brings something extra that I'm not aware of. BTW in the documentation I gave earlier there's no words about docker-machine

Comment: I'm using Docker-Machine as oppose to another way of deploying it because I'm studying a material where the whole deploying process is made through Docker. I know I could use AWS wizard to create an instance but why doing that if Docker can do it natively with few commands in the command line and you can interact with the instance using SSH ? What is strange about my situation is that I'm able to create and run the instance through command line using Docker-Machine but I can't use commands where SSH is involved.

Comment: and here is where I get confused. You don't need to have a docker-machine to work in a local environment. The docker daemon works perfectly fine on ubuntu without having a VM. You won't need to ssh anywhere since it'll be completely native. The docker-machine was/is required for non linux systems.